# Java server can't send bytes below 0 to PHP website

Tags: java, php, sockets

I'm running a Java server that uses the Twitter API and collects search results about any given keyword. My goal is to send the results to my website in PHP. However some Tweets have text with bytes less than 0, these appear to be unicode characters or similar. I've had to replace all of those characters with a space for the packet to be sent at all. If a byte less than 0 is sent the PHP script just reads "null". I need to be able to send bytes of any value, even if they're below 0.

Java: Replace bytes below value 0 with a space

```
// Get the Tweet text
String text = content.getData(2);
// Get the bytes
byte [] bytes = text.getBytes();
// Replace any byte below 0 with a space
for(int a = 0; a < bytes.length; ++a) {
    if(bytes[a] < 0) {
        bytes[a] = " ".getBytes()[0];
    }
}
// Put the bytes back into a String
text = new String(bytes);
```

Java: Server that listens to commands and replies with output

```
ServerSocket socket = null;
InputStreamReader inputStream = null;
BufferedReader input = null;
try {
    socket = new ServerSocket(port);
    Logger.log("Server running on port " + port);
    while(running) {
        connection = socket.accept();
        inputStream = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        input = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        // Run the command we're given, in this case the command will request Twitter search results
        String reply = runCommand(input.readLine());
        // Reply(String) will reply with the results
        reply(reply);
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        connection.close();
        response.close();
        if(inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if(input != null) {
            input.close();
        }
        if(socket != null) {
            socket.close();
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Java: Reply method to send the results of the command execution (in this case it'll send the Twitter search results)

```
private void reply(String reply) {
    try {
        response = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        response.writeUTF(reply);
        response.flush();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

PHP: Send commands (Twitter search query) via sockets and get the reply (Tweet data)

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
try {
    socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);

    // Encode the message in UTF-8, is this correct do to?
    $message = utf8_encode($message);

    // Get the result of sending this message to my Java server
    $status = socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), MSG_EOF, $address, $port);

    // Decode and return the results, is this the correct way to do this?
    if($status != false)  {
        if($next = utf8_decode(socket_read($socket, $port))) {
            return substr($next, 2);
        }
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {

}
// Even when I console.log the return of this method and it comes out "null" it is never this. I've tried changing this to return "-1" and other values and it still always returned "null" as if it was returning the string "null" in the above if statements.
return null;
```

I believe it may be important to note that bottom comment in PHP. I've tried looking over Google for a while now about this and I'm not sure if I'm doing things wrong or if I'm searching for the wrong thing.

How would I send bytes that are less than 0 through this system?

Comment: "bytes below 0" not sure they exist in this universe

Comment: @Dagon this is Java, where the `byte` data type is signed.

Comment: @GatorFlores why are you using `byte`s instead of `char`s?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Until I ran into this problem I didn't attempt to edit the bytes at all. When I looked into what was causing the problem I saw that it occurred whenever a byte was below 0 so I decide to replace them with a space to test if it was the problem, now I'm here.